# How to get only the element i have selected not all elements with same id? (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello how i get only the element i select, without getting all elements with the same id ?
[image: img]

[image]

code : istProj.blade.php (i only tried with id label)

```
 @foreach ($proiecte->istoricProiecte as $istProj)
     <input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ $istProj->proiecte_id }}" name='denumire_proiect' placeholder="Introduceti numele clientului" readonly>
 @endforeach
```

i want to get all the data from the first image table, so i have for example: id proiect = 1, tip actiune = plata, colaborator = 1, suma = 500, data = ... and i want when i press on the eye to go into a page with all those details into labels for deleting the data or update the data.

my IstoricProiecte.php model:

```
protected $table = 'IstoricProiecte';
public $fillable = [
    'id',
    'proiect_id',
    'action_type',
    'colaborator_id',
    'suma',
    'data'
];
use HasFactory;

// un model(istoric proiecte) apartine proiect
public function Proiecte()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Proiecte::class);
}

public function setDataAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['data'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

my Proiecte.php model:

```
protected $table = 'Proiecte';
public $fillable = [
    'id',
    'Denumire_Client',
    'Firma_Client',
    'Reprezentant_Firma',
    'Contact_Client',
    'Suma_Proiect',
    'Numar_Transe',
    'Status_Proiect'
];
use HasFactory;

public function istoricProiecte()
{
    return $this->hasMany(istoricProiecte::class);
}
```

ViewProjController.php

```
public function viewIstProj($id)
{
    $proiecte = Proiecte::find($id);
    $istoric = IstoricProiecte::all();
    $colaborator = Colaboratori::all();
    $time = Carbon::now()->format('m/d/Y');
    // $ist = DB::table('IstoricProiecte')->select('IstoricProiecte.*')->join('Proiecte', 'id', '=', 'IstoricProiecte.id_proiect')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return view('istProj', compact('proiecte', 'istoric', 'colaborator', 'time'));
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('istProj/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ViewProjController::class, 'viewIstProj'])->name('viewIstProj');
```

Comment: Ids are unique, it's not possible to have two elements with the same id, you can't have two projects with the same id.

Comment: @Lk77 i insert collaborators(payments, recieve money) for the project id = 1. so i can have many transactions for id = 1. so i attach transactions for project_id = x ( it is not column for id)

Comment: I think you had better describe your database structure

Comment: @bigwall no you can't have multiple transactions with id 1, ids are unique in a database table, you can have multiple transactions with project_id=1 however, but each transaction has it's own id. You need to use the id of the resource you want to see, not foreign keys like project_id

Comment: @Lk77 yes i know i can t have multiple transactions with id 1, i meant for project_id = 1 i have multiple transactions. and if i have multiple transactions for project_id = 1 i want to get only the one where i press on the eye for(look initial post). how do i do that ?

Comment: @bigwall you pass the id of the transaction you want to see in the route, not the project_id

Comment: @Lk77 if i use id, i go for a foreach loop, and it displays the same, 2 entries because i have 2 transactions on a project_id. how do i display just the one who i pressed for

Comment: @bigwall then you are using the wrong id, likely project_id

Comment: @Lk77 yeah good idea i tried but i got an error Attempt to read property "istoricProiecte" on null. 
yes it was a good idea for using the route for id, not for foreign key. but i got error, i'll try to ffigure it out

Comment: @bigwall remove the foreach and only do : `<input type="text" class='form-control' value="{{ $istProj->id }}" name='denumire_proiect' placeholder="Introduceti numele clientului" readonly>`

Comment: @Lk77 undefined variable $istProj

Comment: @bigwall then `$proiecte->id`, and also be aware that `$proiecte->istoricProiecte->first()->proiecte_id` is strictly equal to `$proiecte->id`. You are accessing the relation to retrieve the foreign key of the model you came from, that does not really make sense and you will get `id` anyway

Comment: @Lk77 Attempt to read property "id" on nul with $proiecte->id

Comment: @bigwall i don't really know the name of the variable, i'm trying to guess, show us the controller to see what you are passing to the view

Comment: @Lk77 check initial post

Comment: @bigwall replace `Proiecte::find($id)` with `Proiecte::findOrFail($id)` and if your getting 404, the id your passing is wrong. Your project was not found, that's why it's null

Comment: @Lk77 it only "works" if i use foreach and $istProj->id but he gets me all the id's inserted in the table.

Comment: @bigwall it never works, you have id=1 everywhere so you think it works, but it don't

Comment: @Lk77 im getting 404

Comment: @bigwall either your id is null or it's not the correct id, or your using the wrong model, try with `IstoricProiecte::findOrFail($id)` instead, perhaps that's what you want to retrieve

Comment: it worked. i replaced with this:$istoric = IstoricProiecte::findOrFail($id); and at value it put  $istoric->id